# A managed subview of UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit

I have a UITableView that I populate with cells in the normal fashion using the datasource and delegate. I would like to add a custom subview, that does the following:

1) scrolls with the UITableView

2) is seen beneath the UITableView scrollbar

3) can be moved and animated independently of any cell (acts as a selector that animates from one cell to the next)

I know how to animate a selector over the top of the UITableView, but that violates requirement #2 (it makes the scrollbar look terrible)

Has anyone seen an implementation of this, or know the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

- Have a base view.
- Add your custom subview to the base view.
- Then add your table view on top of it to the base view.
- Implement the table's scroll delegates and move the custom subview.

Comment: Yes, that is similar to my current implementation. The problem with your suggestion is that the custom view would be behind everything else in the table view.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking at the top of my head, couldn't you disable the scrollbar for the table view and place a transparent scroll view with the same dimension as the table view on top.  You're effectively using the scroll bar of the scroll view instead of the table view.  You'd scroll the scroll view in step with the table view.

Comment: I like the suggestion, but it doesn't seem like good practice. I'd rather have a small graphical problem then multiple scroll views.